# Accessing SparkSession on executor throws error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My code flow is something like below. `get_row_group_info(path)` part gets executed on executor. I am having some logic for logging some data points. Running the flow throws an error as:

```
SparkSession._activeSession.sparkContext\
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sparkContext'
```

```
def logger(mssg):
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    SparkSession._activeSession.sparkContext\
    ._jvm.com.package.logInfoEvent(msg)

def get_file_system():
    #some logging logic
    logger.logInfo("Triggered")
    return fs

def get_row_group_info(path):
    fs = get_file_system()
    relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, base_path)
    pq_file = fs.open(path)
    num_row_groups = pq.read_metadata(pq_file).num_row_groups
    pq_file.close()
    return relative_path, num_row_groups

row_groups = spark_context.parallelize(paths, len(paths)) \
    .map(get_row_group_info) \
    .collect()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can't get Spark context inside executor, it's only accessible via driver. If you just want to know which file is being processed per row, you can try this function [input_file_name](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the ways to get SparkContext from active SparkSession:

1. For spark version < 3.0.0

   SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext
2. For spark version >= 3.0.0

   SparkSession.getActiveSession().sparkContext // [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession)

Comment: Getting the same error when running with SparkSession.getActiveSession().sparkContext